# Board game design in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, design-patterns, template

I'm trying to build a board game and solve it using algorithms such as Monte Carlo Tree Search in C++. My current design follows [this python project](https://github.com/aimacode/aima-python), in which I have a class hierarchy for `Board` and a `State` template as follows

```cpp
// board.hpp
#ifndef GAME_BOARD_H_
#define GAME_BOARD_H_

#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#include "basics.hpp"

namespace game {    
    class Board {
    public:
        using type = std::vector<std::vector<Piece>>;
        explicit Board(int);
        Board(const Board&);
        Board(Board&&);

        Board& operator=(const Board&);
        Board& operator=(Board&&);

        virtual ~Board() {}

        virtual void display() const = 0;

        /* Queries */
        bool is_on_board(Point p) const { return is_on_board(p.first, p.second); }
        bool is_valid(Point p) const { return is_valid(p.first, p.second); }
        
        /* Access */
        std::unordered_set<Point, PointHash> get_valid_moves();
        Piece get_piece(Point p) const { return get_piece(p.first, p.second); }
        int get_board_size() const { return n; }

        /* Modifiers */
        bool reset(Point);
        bool move(Point, Piece);
    protected:
        bool is_on_board(int i, int j) const { return i >= 0 && i < n && j >= 0 && j < n; }
        virtual bool is_valid(int i, int j) const = 0;

        const type& get_board() const { return board; }
        Piece get_piece(int i, int j) const { return board[i][j]; }
    private:
        int n;
        type board;
    };
}

#endif
```

```cpp
// state.hpp
#ifndef GAME_STATE_H_
#define GAME_STATE_H_

#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>

#include "basics.hpp"

namespace game {
    template<typename Board>
    class State {
    public:
        State(Board={}, Piece=Piece::White, int u=0);
        State(const State&);
        State(State&&);
        
        State& operator=(const State&);
        State& operator=(State&&);

        ~State() {}
        
        void display() const { board.display(); }
        bool is_over() const;

        /* Modifiers */
        bool update_board(Point, Piece);
        void update_utility(int);

        /* Access */
        int get_utility() const { return utility; }
        // get utility for piece p
        int get_utility(Piece p) const { return p == curr_piece? utility: -utility; }
        Piece to_move() const { return next_piece(curr_piece); }
        const Board& get_board() const { return board; }
        std::unordered_set<Point, PointHash> get_valid_moves() { return valid_moves; }
    private:
        Piece curr_piece;
        Board board;
        int utility;
        Point curr_move;
        std::unordered_set<Point, PointHash> valid_moves;
    };
}

template<typename Board>
game::State<Board>::State(Board b, Piece p, int u):
        board(b), curr_piece(p), utility(u) {
    valid_moves = board.get_valid_moves();
}

template<typename Board>
game::State<Board>::State(const State& rhs): 
        curr_piece(rhs.curr_piece), 
        board(rhs.board),
        utility(rhs.utility),
        curr_move(rhs.curr_move) {
    
}

template<typename Board>
game::State<Board>::State(State&& rhs):
        curr_piece(rhs.curr_piece),
        board(std::move(rhs.board)),
        utility(rhs.utility),
        curr_move(rhs.curr_move) {
}

template<typename Board>
game::State<Board>& game::State<Board>::operator=(const State& rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        auto tmp = rhs;
        swap(*this, tmp);
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename Board>
game::State<Board>& game::State<Board>::operator=(State&& rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        curr_piece = rhs.curr_piece;
        swap(board, rhs.board);
        utility = rhs.utility;
        curr_move = rhs.curr_move;
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename Board>
bool game::State<Board>::update_board(Point point, Piece piece) {
    curr_piece = piece;
    curr_move = point;

    auto succ = board.move(point, piece);
    if (succ)
        valid_moves.erase(point);
    
    return succ;
}

template<typename Board>
void game::State<Board>::update_utility(int u) {
    utility = u;
}

#endif
```

I define `Board` as a base class so that derived classes can have their own implementation of `display` and `is_valid`. For example, the following code is my implementation of these functions for [Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game))

```cpp
// hex_board.cpp
    
void HexBoard::display() const {
    static constexpr char RESET[] = "\033[0m";
    static constexpr char RED[] = "\033[31m";
    static constexpr char BLUE[] = "\033[34m";
    auto n = get_board_size();
    for (auto i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        std::cout << std::string(i, ' ');
        for (auto j = 0; j != n; ++j) {
            auto x = Board::get_piece(i, j);
            switch (x) {
                case Piece::Blank: std::cout << ". "; 
                    break;
                case Piece::White: std::cout << RED << "x " << RESET; 
                    break;
                case Piece::Black: std::cout << BLUE << "o " << RESET; 
                    break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

vector<Point> game::HexBoard::get_adjacent_points(Point point, Piece piece) const {
    int i = point.first, j = point.second;
    int n = get_board_size();
    std::vector<Point> ans;
    for (const auto& s: HexNeighbor) {
        int x = i + s.first, y = j + s.second;
        if (is_on_board(x, y) && get_piece(x, y) == piece) {
            ans.push_back(make_pair(x, y));
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

The `State` is a template because it owns a `Board`. If I define it as a plain class, then it has to store the board via a (smart) pointer so that it can point to a subclass of `Board`. I don't do that in the first place because in algorithms, like Monte Carlo tree search, we usually have to create many subsequent `State`s so as to see which action performs best. Regarding the number of potential states the algorithm has to create, I think it's better to put `State`s on the heap. And if `State` stores a pointer to `Board` then there will be two indirect access, which I'm not so sure if it's good.

Now I'm about to write `Player`, in which algorithms such as Monte Catlo tree search are implemented. Now a problem arises: because `Player` takes in `State` to make an action and `State` is a template, `Player` has also to be a template. On the other hand, I'd like to define `Player` as a base class so that subclasses can implement different strategies. I know that defining a hierarchy on a template class can cause [code bloating](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-rules-for-templates-and-hierarchies) because of the virtual functions. This makes me rethink all design and I come with two solutions

1. Don't define any virtual function in `Player` and subclass it for different algorithms. This dispenses with the concerns of code bloating. Furthermore, I can define `Board` as a template and specialize it for different games as I don't think there is a need for dynamic binding.
2. Define `State` as a plain class that contains a smart pointer to `Board`. In this way, there is no template anymore.

Which one is a better way to go? How should I make the choice? Or are there any other better solutions?

Comment: How many different boards/algorithms do you think you will have?  Unless there's tons of them that work simultaneously, I wouldn't worry about code boating at this point, and I would simply remove all the virtual functions and use templates.  But that's subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inevitably, as you have mentioned, it all comes down to the choice
between two approaches — templates and virtuals.  These two
approaches each have their own benefits and drawbacks.

The problem with your current code, though, is that it mixes the two
approaches in a suboptimal way.  Your `Board` class is intended to be
an interface, but it tries to implement a common representation as
well.  The problem with this approach is that it forces subclasses to
carry the same data, which often turns out to be unnecessary and
burdensome — the square representation used in `Board` may not
turn out suitable for all boards, for example.  (See also [C.121](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c121-if-a-base-class-is-used-as-an-interface-make-it-a-pure-abstract-class))

To solve this problem, we first destroy the interface nature of
`Board`, and rename it to reflect that it only serves as a helper for
implementing square boards:

```cpp
class RectangularBoardBase /* : public Board */ {
public:
    explicit RectangularBoardBase(std::size_t size_);
    // default implementations that subclasses can inherit
    // if they do not require special treatment
    void display() const /* override */;
    bool is_valid(Point) const /* override */;
    // ... queries, accessors, modifiers ...
protected:
    using Representation = std::vector<std::vector<Piece>>;
    // ... implementation helpers ...
private:
    std::size_t size;
    Representation pieces;
};
```

note that the special member functions are gone, and that `display`
has been reduced to an ordinary member function in case you have a
default rectangular display (you can get rid of it altogether if there
is no default display, as is the case with your original code, where
you leave `display` pure virtual).

After this point, the solutions are slightly different for the two
approaches.

---

## Approach 1 — templates

Board types derive from `RectangularBoardBase` if it is helpful, or,
for non-rectangular boards, start from scratch.  For board types that
implement their own `display`, like `HexBoard`, simply ignore the
`display` from the base class.  The board types are related by the
common interface that you decide without the presence of a common base
class.

For maintenance, you can make a concept (since C++20) or add a set of
old-style `static_asserts` to your tests to make sure that board types
implement the common interface.

The board type becomes a template parameter of `State`, and `State`
stores the `Board` directly.

---

## Approach 2 — virtuals

Make the interface class an abstract class with pure virtuals only:

```cpp
class Board {
public:
    virtual void display() const = 0;
    virtual bool is_valid(Point) const = 0;
    // ... other common virtuals, if necessary ...
    virtual ~Board() {}
protected:
    Board() = default;
    Board(const Board&) = default;
    Board& operator=(const Board&) = default;
};
```

`RectangularBoardBase` derives from `Board`, and board types then
indirectly derive from this interface and implement the virtual
methods accordingly:

```cpp
class HexBoard : public RectangularBoardBase {
public:
    // ...
    using RectangularBoardBase::RectangularBoardBase;
    // own version of display
    void display() const override;
    // inherit existing is_valid
private:
    //...
};
```

Alternatively, a board type may derive directly from `Board` and start
from scratch if `RectangularBoardBase` is unhelpful:

```cpp
class EmptyBoard : public Board {
public:
    Emptyboard() = default;

    void display() const override {
        std::cout << "nothing\n";
    }
    bool is_valid(Point) const override {
        return false;
    }

    // ...
};
```

`State` contains a `std::unique_ptr<Board>`, and accesses the board
through dynamic dispatch.

---

## Miscellaneous issues

`std::vector<std::vector<Piece>>` is not a compact representation
— it stores the pieces noncontiguously, allows jagged boards,
and introduces double allocation and double indirection overhead.  The
usual solution is to flatten the representation into a
`std::vector<Piece>` and calculate indexes on the fly.

You seem to have the habit of writing out special member functions
(copy/move constructors/assignment operators) manually, which is not
necessary.  Leave them out, and the compiler will be able to
synthesize optimal versions of them on its own.  An exception is when
a virtual destructor is present — ideally, this should only
happen in an abstract base class, where the issue is resolved as I
demonstrated above.

Instead of `int`, use `std::size_t` to store indexes and dimensions.
Also, it seems unnecessary to have both `(Point)` and `(int, int)`
overloads — I'd keep the first.

Is there a specific reason why `White` is considered the default
piece?  If there isn't, I'd consider mandating the `Piece` argument in
the constructor of `State`.

Consider making `display` take an `std::ostream&` argument for extra
flexibility.  Instead of `char` arrays, you can use
[`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) (C++17) for more type safety.  Instead of
`endl`, consider using `\n` to avoid unnecessary performance drop due
to gratuitous flushing ([`std::endl` vs `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907)).

---

Last, all of the design choices I presented here are general
guidelines only, and the details may have been somewhat arbitrary.
Since you have a much more comprehensive grasp of your project, feel
free to make modifications and adapt them to your needs as
appropriate.

Comment: Hello and thank you so much for the review and insightful feedback. I learned a lot from your feedback and have modified my code as you suggested. I've implemented both versions and found the template version was more tedious as I had to define all functions that invoked Board and Player as templates too.  BTW, the default choice of piece should be Blank or Black(White was a mistake) as in general board game the player with white piece moves first.